# Different output from scrapy spider than from scrapy shell

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to scrapy and am attempting to figure out why I am able to extract the elements I need from the scrapy shell but not from the scrapy spider I created from command line.

In scrapy shell I did the following:

```
pipenv run scrapy shell http://quotes.toscrape.com/
```

Then

```
response.css('small.author::text').extract()
```

Which returns the following:

> ['Albert Einstein', 'J.K. Rowling', 'Albert Einstein', 'Jane Austen', 'Marilyn Monroe', 'Albert Einstein', 'André Gide', 'Thomas A. Edison', 'Eleanor Roosevelt', 'Steve Martin']

This is all as intended. But I start to have some issues when I create a scrapy spider and run it afterwards. My code is below:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy

class Yolo1Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'yolo1'
    allowed_domains = ['toscrape.com']
    start_urls = ['http://http://quotes.toscrape.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        self.log('Just visited' + response.url)
        yield {
            'author': response.css('small.author::text').extract()
            }
```

I run the spider from the command line with:

```
pipenv run scrapy crawl yolo1
```

The errors I get are as follows:

> 2017-12-04 20:03:56 [yolo1] DEBUG: Just visitedhttp://www.dnsrsearch.com/index.php?origURL=http://http/quotes.toscrape.com/&bc=
>   2017-12-04 20:03:56 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error processing {'author': []}
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "c:\users\alice.virtualenvs\all-the-places-c44chfla\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 653, in _runCallbacks
>       current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
>     File "C:\Users\alice\all-the-places\locations\pipelines.py", line 16, in process_item
>       ref = item['ref']
>   KeyError: 'ref'

I get the feeling I am just missing something simple but for the life of me I cannot figure it out and have been checking all over the place.

You can see in the output of the spider crawl that the debug line I wrote printed out, but after that I get an error. Really thought I should be getting the same output from both the spider and the command line work I did.

Comment: you have `http://` twice in url - see `'http://http://quotes.toscrape.com/`

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake in start url - you have `http://` twice.

See `http://http://quotes.toscrape.com/`

Comment: Thanks so much. Sometimes you just really need a fresh set of eyes on these things.